# MySQL 1:10 fixed relationship. How to implement it at database level?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Is it possible to implement a 1:N relationship that has 10 rows of the `many` referencing 1 row from the `one` table at most?

```
// ID int
INSERT INTO one VALUES (1);
// ...
INSERT INTO one VALUES (25);

//ID int, one_id int
INSERT INTO many VALUES (1,1);
// ...
INSERT INTO many VALUES (1,10);
INSERT INTO many VALUES (1,11); // ERROR!

INSERT INTO many VALUES (2,11); // working
// ...
INSERT INTO many VALUES (2,20); // working
INSERT INTO many VALUES (2,21); // ERROR!
```

Comment: with a stored procedure (or whatever they are called in msql): yes. In native sql: no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a trigger:

```
create trigger trg_mytable_max10 before insert on mytable
for each row
begin
  declare cnt int;
  set cnt = (select count(*) from mytable where col1 = new.col1);
  if cnt = 10 then
    signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'only 10 records per col1 allowed';
  end if;
end;
```

http://rextester.com/EORH56497

Comment: I intented to use something at create table level, but if this is the only way I will accept this answer as it's working.

Comment: I think this is about the only way. There is no constraint you could apply to the table instead.

Comment: Then this is accepted for me. Thank you for your help!